# Python-Order a list so that X follows Y and Y follows X

Tags: python, django

So I am using the python chain method to combine two querysets (lists) in django like this.

```
results=list(chain(data,tweets[:5]))
```

Where data and tweets are two separate lists. I now have a "results" list with both data and tweet objects that I want ordered in this fashion.

```
results=[data,tweets,data,tweets,data,tweets]
```

What is the best way to achieve this kind of ordering? I tried using random.shuffle but this isnt what I want.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want: 1. results = [data[0], tweets[0], data[1],tweets[1],...]  or 2. results = [data[0],data[1],...,data[n],tweets[0],...,tweets[n],data[0],data[1],...]

Comment: Are you sure this is the output format you want? Would `zip(data, tweets)` not be more useful here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `itertools.chain.from_iterable` and `zip`:

```
>>> data = [1,2,3,4] 
>>> tweets = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(zip(data,tweets)))
[1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 'd']
```

Use `itertools.izip` for memory efficient solution.

Comment: Ah, `from_iterable` is the elegant way to flatten the zipped list that I was missing.

Comment: @Oleg, not if the lists are very long (which is likely in this case)

Comment: Since we're listing inferior alternatives, `(v for t in zip(data, tweets) for v in t)`

Comment: @Eric, you should post that as a separate answer. Yours is the most readable of the lot. And `izip` in place of `zip` should take care of large input lists

Comment: @oleg, why do you think he trims the list at five? Because analyzing tweets is typically done with huge datasets, and this is for illustration.

Comment: @alexis You are completely right I have removed all my comments they can confuse someone

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution using iterators:

```
from itertools import izip
result = (v for t in izip(data, tweets) for v in t)
```

Comment: That's nice: it's not obvious that alternating the zipped pairs is just list-flattening.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
>>> result = [None]*(len(data)+len(tweets))
>>> result[::2] = data
>>> result[1::2] = tweets
```